# Data rendering issue in angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5

When I have large list of data and I scrolled down my page then it is taking time to render data into html and shows white screen for few seconds. How can we fix this problem?

[issue that I'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZrnY.png)

[code for html binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1nuA.png)

Comment: What did you try? Could you show some code?

Comment: Try adding `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component metadata.

Comment: I tried *lazyFor* and *changeDetection* for this but facing same issue

Comment: issue fixed with ngx virtual scroller and trackBy.

Answer (score 0):

Its always not a good practise to render a big chunk of data on the DOM because it will draw in DOM , so increase memory result in taking long time to load other data it will result in bad user Experience. so in order to achieve good performance and avoid this problem use virtual scrolling.

you can implement virtual scroll in angular using CDK. follow the below url
https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview.

Hope it will help.

Comment: I tried ngx virtual scroller and trackby to fix this issue. Now its working fine for me. Thanks